# What is the difference between scale and zoom in webview?

Tags: android, webview, zooming, scale

What is the difference between scale and zoom?
What is the definition of scale? and What setInitialScale function does?

Answer (score 1):

**Scale:** The contents can't be scaled down more than `'overview scale'` (that is, such that your content is narrower than the screen). This is by design - making it smaller only results in rendering white to the sides. If you want this behavior you'd need to add padding to the content,you've specified the layout height of the `WebView` to be `WRAP_CONTENT`

- this makes the `WebView` ignore the `viewport` meta tag.
- set it to `MATCH_PARENT` or a fixed size.

You're using certain `WebSettings`:

```
  setUseWideViewport (which overrides the viewport meta tag) or
  setInitialScale (which can alter the size of the viewport).
```

**setInitialScale (int scaleInPercent)**

Sets the initial scale for this `WebView`. **0** means default. The behavior for the default scale depends on the state of `getUseWideViewPort()` and `getLoadWithOverviewMode()`. If the content fits into the WebView control by width, then the zoom is set to 100%. For wide content, the behavior depends on the state of `getLoadWithOverviewMode()`. If its value is true, the content will be zoomed out to be fit by width into the `WebView` control, otherwise not. If initial scale is greater than 0, `WebView` starts with this value as initial scale. Please note that unlike the scale properties in the viewport meta tag, this method doesn't take the screen density into account.

**Parameters**

*scaleInPercent* - the initial scale in percent

Comment: I don't understand. ZoomIn make the webview content bigger and ZoomOut make the webview content smaller. So what the scaling operation does?

Answer (score 0):

[SetInitialScale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setInitialScale%28int%29)

> Sets the initial scale for this WebView. 0 means default. The behavior
>   for the default scale depends on the state of getUseWideViewPort() and
>   getLoadWithOverviewMode(). If the content fits into the WebView
>   control by width, then the zoom is set to 100%. For wide content, the
>   behavor depends on the state of getLoadWithOverviewMode(). If its
>   value is true, the content will be zoomed out to be fit by width into
>   the WebView control, otherwise not. If initial scale is greater than
>   0, WebView starts with this value as initial scale. Please note that
>   unlike the scale properties in the viewport meta tag, this method
>   doesn't take the screen density into account.

So setInitialScale is used to scale the native view of android. It's like in native Android browser when you scale the content with 2 fingers.

Comment: I don't understand. ZoomIn make the webview content bigger and ZoomOut make the webview content smaller. So what the scaling operation does?

Comment: Do you say that open 2 fingers on the screen it is scaling? It seems to be zoom, isn't it?

Comment: @rafraph No zoom is the native zoom of the browser

Comment: OK. Please try to explain again what setInitialScale  does? What is the meaning of "Initial" in this function name? Why it doesn't called setScale?